# Unable to mount/access Virtual Box Guest Additions

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, guest-additions, bitnami

I checked many questions on this topic but none worked for me. I keep getting the error in the image shown below. There is nothing under the `media` folder to install manually too. The mount just fails. Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: Try what the error message suggest us dmesg|tail to get more info. But I suspect a corrupted iso as it usually works fine.